# Cannot create an object using factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

My code:

```
webApp.controller ('entityCtrl', function ($scope, Entity) {  
    $scope.x = new Entity('1','3343','32434');
});


webApp.factory('Entity',function(){

  var _id,
      _created,
      _updated;


  //constructor

  function Entity(id,created,updated){


      this._id = id;
      this._created = created;
      this._updated = updated;

      return this;
  }

  var save = function (){
      console.log('save');
  };

  var update = function () {
      console.log('update');
  };

  var _delete = function () {
      console.log('delete');
};

  return {

      save: save,
      update: update,
      delete: _delete
  }

});
```

The Error I get:

```
TypeError: object is not a function
at new <anonymous> (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/rw/controllers.js:12:16)
at invoke (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:2902:28)
at Object.instantiate (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:2914:23)
at $get (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:4805:24)
at $get.i (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:4384:17)
at forEach (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:137:20)
at nodeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:4369:11)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:4015:15)
at compositeLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:4018:13)
at publicLinkFn (http://localhost/webApp/trunk/htdocs/js/vendors/angular.js:3920:30)    angular.js:5754
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has actually little to do with Angular. You're returning an Object (as the error says) from the method. You may want to return your `Entity` function.

Consider this example:

```
webApp.controller ('entityCtrl', function ($scope, Entity) {  
    $scope.x = new Entity('1','3343','32434');
});

webApp.factory('Entity',function(){
  var Entity = function(id,created,updated){
      this._id = id;
      this._created = created;
      this._updated = updated;
  };
  Entity.prototype.save = function (){
      console.log('save');
  };
  Entity.prototype.update = function () {
      console.log('update');
  };
  Entity.prototype._delete = function () {
      console.log('delete');
  };

  return Entity;
});
```

Btw. you may want to watch this video, on how the Object Oriented JS works : http://youtu.be/PMfcsYzj-9M

Comment: Throws me a new error `TypeError: Object function (id,created,updated){
        this._id = id;
        this._created = created;
        this._updated = updated;`

Comment: Cannot be ;) : checkout this Plunkr http://plnkr.co/edit/ygi5OePQwSkLQt8Uthi1?p=preview

Comment: Yes you are right, there seems to be problem displaying {{x}}, anyway it works thanks man!

Comment: By the way, I read a little about JS OOP, can you explain why to use prototype? Isn't that just a way to define a public methods?

Comment: Not really, JS doesn't have explicit way to define visibility (like Java does for example), it is a way to define inheritance - please check the link I've attached.

Comment: Yes I'd do it today, I suppose that this article I read: http://phrogz.net/js/classes/OOPinJS.html has just confused me then

Comment: It is a bit confusing, if you have for example Java background, because the name JavaScript contains Java in it, but it's actually fundamentally different language ;)